# Clicking the Settings button when the red bar "GPS signal not found" hides it

Tags: pokemon-go, android

How can I click the Settings button on the top right corner of the screen, when the "GPS signal not found" red bar, or some other bar (such as the tutorial's "Find a Pokestop near you") is blocking it?

Below, I got two screenshots (not mine) illustrating the issue: the first one shows the red bar (on top of the game screen), and the second one shows the menu, with the settings button on top. Combine both, and you have my issue: the red bar goes *above* the settings button, making it impossible to reach. Tapping on top of it does nothing.

[image: GPS signal not found]

[image: menu with settings button]

Comment: In short: you can't.

Comment: I refuse to believe such a ridiculous interface bug would be present in the world's most downloaded mobile game...

Comment: (more seriously, please post it as an answer, I'd prefer finding it written on stone than searching fruitlessly for a solution on some website)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't tap on settings when the "GPS signal not found" banner is active. I've actually had this happen to me and wanted to change a setting, but could not. The banner, which is non-interactive, ends up being the focus of all touch events within it's area, preventing you from interacting with any controls that it covers.

In my case, simply restarting the application fixed my GPS issue so that I could alter my settings.

Answer (score 0):

There is no exit option in the game app so you need to kill the application from menu or close it directly and it might be a case when bar appeared you need to restart the game for better performance.